# Java FileSystemView Hidden Folder

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I have an applet for uploading file, and when browse file, it showed all folder normally just like normal except it does not show hidden folder. My question is, is it possible to show hidden folder also in the file browser?

I am using java 1.6 and javax.swing.filechooser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting false to the method setFileHidingEnabled() of JFileChooser lets hidden files be shown.
see : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 3):

[Hiding files](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Toenablethedisplayofhiddenfiles.htm) in Swing [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html):

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [setFileHidingEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileHidingEnabled%28boolean%29) method of JFileChooser.

This method

> Sets file hiding on or off. If true, hidden files are not shown in the
>   file chooser. The job of determining which files are shown is done by
>   the FileView.

```
fileChooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
```